# Установка SSl сетификата в Docker Keycloak

Tags: ssl, devops, keycloak

Ребят, подскажите нубасу кодеру, как правильно подкинуть SSL сертификат для Keycloak в Docker контейнере.

Имеется контейнер с Keycloak v.15.0.2
И имеется незащищенное соединение с сервисом по https

Наш devOps наколдовал *.crt и *.key без пароля.
После него я уже тоже наколдовал еще пару crt и key c паролями

```
openssl req -x509 -days 365 -newkey rsa:2048 -keyout tls.key -out tls.crt
```

Преобразовал их в *.p12

```
openssl pkcs12 -export -out newtls.p12 -inkey newtls.key -in newtls.crt
```

Преобразовал *.p12 в *.jks

```
keytool -importkeystore -srckeystore tls.p12 -srcstoretype PKCS12 -destkeystore tls.jks -deststoretype JKS
```

И как теперь все это добро корректно закинуть?
Пробовал в standlone.xml закинуть, но тоже не получилось.